# I want to make my Android app min API 8. The docs give me functions that are not available in API 8. Where should I look?

Tags: android

Sorry, I had some trouble writing a short title for this!

I want my app to have a minimum API level of 8. But Google's docs don't care. They only document the API in its most up-to-date form. I know that the things I want to do were possible before API 9, but how can I find out how they were done "back then"?

The case in point, by the way, is [getCameraInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getCameraInfo%28int,%20android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo%29). In fact, the whole Camera.CameraInfo class only existed since API 9, but there must, before API 9, have been a way to get information about the phone's camera.

I can't seem to make any headway on this issue (even just the specific CameraInfo example). Is the only answer to cut out 20% of my userbase and make 9 the minimum API level? What about when, as the app progresses, I find that a feature I want to use requires, according to the docs, a class that was brought in in API 12?

**Edit:** Oh gahd... this is awkward and unlikely. I didn't specify, but the info I'm actually looking for is the physical orientation of the camera's sensor. Thanks to one of the replies below, I saw on [this page](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.2.html) that before API 9 this was a non-issue, as those versions of Android only allowed photos in "portrait" mode. I'm still left with lots of questions about Android's fragmentation, but at least I now understand that the new CameraInfo class didn't *replace* anything. Nothing is *removed* as the docs are updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.2.html) link. info about API Level 8 (Android 2.2)

At the bottom you can see there is a section called Camera and camcorder which specifies the changes in that level regarding the camera. Could be that this specific method `getCameraInfo()` is only available since API 9, but there are ways in API 8 to get the same info using different methods.

Also, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) is a direct link to the entire documentation of the Camera object. You can read of all the available methods and their API levels.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the documentation by API level. Go to http://developer.android.com and select the "reference" section. At the top of the column on the left-hand side it says **"Android APIs API level:"** followed by a dropdown selection. Set that to **"8"**. Then you will only see stuff available in API level 8.

Comment: So now I can't see the CameraInfo class, but I still don't know  how I can get information about the camera. Am I wrong in my assumption that there was some other thing that the CameraInfo class replaced? Before API 9 was there really no way in the API to find the orientation of the camera's sensor?

Comment: (see edit to OP). Nope, there really was no way to find the orientation of the camera's sensor. CameraInfo didn't replace anything. Thanks!